# How to "dequote" a stringLiteral in Scala parser combinator?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I was wondering if there is an easy way I'm unaware of at the moment to remove `"` characters from the beginning and end of a `stringLiteral` captured by a `TokenParser`?

I searched through the Scaladocs but haven't found a handy util function for it. Yeah, I can surely do it by playing with `substring(1, str.length - 1)` but my gut feeling is that it is already written somewhere I'm just cannot find it :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please add your parser to the question. It's possible you could change `stringLiteral` parser like `def stringLiteral = '"' ~> withoutQuote <~ '"'`.

Comment: The definition of `stringLiteral` looks like this in `JavaTokenParsers`: `def stringLiteral: Parser[String] = ("\""+"""([^"\p{Cntrl}\\]|\\[\\'"bfnrt]|\\u[a-fA-F0-9{4})*"""+"\"").r`. Where should I find `withoutQuote`? I'd like to avoid redefine the regexp here :-) Rather, I created a simple util function that makes the substring-manipulation, it's kind of shorter.

Comment: If you want to use this `stringLiteral` parser than `substring` is the way to go: `def deguoted = stringLiteral ^^ {str => str.substring(1, str.length - 1)} `

Comment: Yeah, that was my own solution too :-) The only thing I changed I made it a function because I had to use it in several places. Can you post it as an aswer so I can accept it? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `stringLiteral` from `JavaTokenParsers` you could create your own parser based on it:

```
def deguoted: Parser[String] = stringLiteral ^^ {str => str.substring(1, str.length - 1)}
```

Comment: Oh, cool, even better than my own solution! You seem to know all the solutions for my dummy questions, senia :-) Thx for your efforts.

Comment: This solution only strips the outer double quotes, and does not convert, for instance, a `\u1234` value to a single Unicode character.  Here is the proper solution: https://github.com/tpolecat/examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/eg/Quote.scala